# Pandas: GroupBy and Order Groups based on max value in each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame which contains tracks, score and some other columns.

I want to group by on "tracks" and then sorting of those groups based on the maximum value on the "score".

**Example DataFrame**:

```
tracks       score
20            2.2
20            1.5
25            3.5
24            1.2
24            5.5
```

**Expected Output** (I want to compare the highest values from each group and sort all the group from highest to lowest, though I don't want to lose any other data - means I want to show all the rows):

```
tracks       score
24            5.5
              1.2
25            3.5
20            2.2
              1.5
```

Currently, I am getting following output (my score is sorted but after group by my tracks are sorted based on the track numbers):

```
    tracks       score
20            2.2
              1.5
24            5.5
              4.2
25            3.5
```

My Approach till now:
1. I've sorted all the values by the score

```
sub_df = sub_df.sort_values("score")
```

2. Then I am doing the following to get the output (I need in dictionary format):

`url_dict = sub_df.groupby('track')['url'].apply(list).to_dict()`

I also tried to used OrderedDict but it is of no use (at least for now) as the groupBy command is sending the wrong sequence of data.

**Pandas = 0.23, Python = 3.6.4**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create helper column by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and sort by multiple columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), last remove helper column:

```
sub_df['max'] = sub_df.groupby('tracks')['score'].transform('max')

sub_df = sub_df.sort_values(["max","score"], ascending=False).drop('max', axis=1)
#if necessary sorting also by tracks column
#sub_df = sub_df.sort_values(["max","tracks","score"], ascending=False).drop('max', axis=1)
print (sub_df)
   tracks  score
4      24    5.5
3      24    1.2
2      25    3.5
0      20    2.2
1      20    1.5
```

Comment: you are a pandas god. you have answered more of my pandas questions than i can count!

Answer (score 2):

may be a bit long but this is what i use:

first set the index:

```
df.set_index(['x', 'y'], inplace=True)
```

then use the groupby on a double sorted dataframe based on the index

```
new_df = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().reset_index() \
          .sort_values(['x', 'y'], ascending=[1,0]).groupby('x').head(1)
```

this will show only the max value, if you want to see all, remove the "head(1)".